# Oracle - Case in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, case, where-clause

I am trying to execute a query in Oracle database. The query has case construction in where clause.

```
where
    sale.op = 2 and
        case when (:stat = -11) then (sale.type_id = 27 or sale.type_id = 28 or sale.type_id = 29)
    else
    (sale.type_id = 27)
    end
```

But I am getting the following error:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis.

In Derby SQL this works.  Does anybody can help me?
Thank you.

Comment: CASE evaluates the conditions and returns an `expression` which needs to be evaluated using an operator to some value/column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
where sale.op = 2 
and (     (:stat = -11 and sale.type_id in (27, 28, 29))
      or  (:stat <> -11 and sale.type_id = 27)
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

try this query:

```
where
    sale.op = 2 and
        ((:stat = -11 and (sale.type_id = 27 or sale.type_id = 28 or sale.type_id = 29)) 
       or (:stat <> -11 and sale.type_id = 27))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try without CASE, using simple operators AND and OR :

```
where
    sale.op = 2 and ((:stat = -11 and (sale.type_id = 27 or sale.type_id = 28 or sale.type_id = 29))  
        OR (:stat <> -11 and sale.type_id = 27))
```

Answer (score 1):

try this query

```
where 
     sale.op =2 and
     ((:stat = -11 and sale.type_id=any(27,28,29)) or
       (:stat <> -11 and sale.type_id = 27))
```

It looks more clear!!!